# conflicting redeclaration of sys/types.h and linux/types.h

Tags: c++, linux

I have compilation errors for my program:

```
/usr/include/sys/types.h:46: error: conflicting declaration ‘typedef __loff_t loff_t’
/usr/include/linux/types.h:30: error: ‘loff_t’ has a previous declaration as ‘typedef __kernel_loff_t loff_t’
/usr/include/sys/types.h:62: error: conflicting declaration ‘typedef __dev_t dev_t’
/usr/include/linux/types.h:13: error: ‘dev_t’ has a previous declaration as ‘typedef __kernel_dev_t dev_t’
/usr/include/time.h:105: error: conflicting declaration ‘typedef void* timer_t’
/usr/include/linux/types.h:22: error: ‘timer_t’ has a previous declaration as ‘typedef __kernel_timer_t timer_t’
/usr/include/sys/types.h:198: error: conflicting declaration ‘typedef long int int64_t’
/usr/include/linux/types.h:98: error: ‘int64_t’ has a previous declaration as ‘typedef __s64 int64_t’
/usr/include/sys/types.h:204: error: conflicting declaration ‘typedef long unsigned int u_int64_t’
/usr/include/linux/types.h:97: error: ‘u_int64_t’ has a previous declaration as ‘typedef __u64 u_int64_t’
/usr/include/sys/select.h:78: error: conflicting declaration ‘typedef struct fd_set fd_set’
/usr/include/linux/types.h:12: error: ‘fd_set’ has a previous declaration as ‘typedef struct __kernel_fd_set fd_set’
/usr/include/sys/types.h:235: error: conflicting declaration ‘typedef __blkcnt_t blkcnt_t’
/usr/include/linux/types.h:124: error: ‘blkcnt_t’ has a previous declaration as ‘typedef long unsigned int blkcnt_t’
```

In my code I didn't include any `types.h` at all, so I suspect it must be those third party `.h` files that have included `sys/types.h` and `linux/type.h`.

How shall I fix this issue?

Comment: Which headers were you including?

Comment: Which version/distro of Linux?

Comment: include libpcan.h which is a linux canbus api and also included all the QT stuff such as qthread,qstring etc. using fedora 11.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a common problem, and yet there are widely different solutions mentioned.

One reasonable solution is to include one of the two headers yourself, before `libpcan.h` or the Qt headers. I can't figure out which one, so you'll have to try both. If this fails, try to include both, and in both orders.